# Should I use the root account on my Digital Ocean server?

Tags: authentication, ssh, sftp

I have set up an SSH key with Digital Ocean that is automatically added to any servers I create. Is it okay to use this root account for SFTP and daily use or should I create another user account and avoid using the root account?

Answer (score 3):

It's generally advisable to not use the root user for everyday tasks, so I would recommend creating a different user account.